# Sketchflow Timer Trigger

Tags: c#, expression-blend, sketchflow

Does anyone know how to create a timer trigger in c# in Expression Blend Sketchflow ?

Comment: What do you want this trigger to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a trigger in the actions/triggers/behaviors sense, drag an action onto the artboard or the timeline, select it, then in the properties pane find the trigger section and click the new button, select the timer trigger.